# Angular duplicates ng-view every time a route is loaded

Tags: angularjs

It's normal that AngularJS creates a new `ng-view` every time a route is loaded, and then destroys the previous `ng-view`? It's just a fraction of time, but I can see both views on my app, and some directives which gather the element top also notice that behaviour (it seems that compilation is done before the original `ng-view` is removed from the DOM)

Has someone noticed this behaviour?

Comment: I believe it's supposed to be like that - so you can add transitions between routes where both exist for a fraction of time.

Comment: using an animated transition you don't notice this behaviour

Comment: I suppose so, but this behaviour is not noticed anywhere in the documentation, as far as I know

Comment: @JavierMarín it's in the documentation: **["The enter and leave animations occur concurrently"](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView#animations)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's normal, this allows you to have transitions when the view gets replaced.

From the **[official documentation of `ngView`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView#animations)**:

> enter - animation is used to bring new content into the browser. leave
>   - animation is used to animate existing content away.
>
> **The enter and leave animation occur concurrently.**

Actually `ngView` is not the only directive that behaves like that, for instance `ngRepeat` behaves exactly the same.

If you want to make sure that your views don't overlap, you could try this.

Add a class to the element of the `ng-view` so that you can easily target it from your css, something like this:

```
<div ng-view class="your-view"></div>
```

And then in your css do this:

```
.your-view.ng-leave { display:none; }
```